# Scrapy, scraping data inside a Javascript

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I am using [`scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/) to screen scrape data from a website. However, the data I wanted wasn't inside the html itself, instead, it is from a javascript. So, my question is:

How to get the values (text values) of such cases?

This, is the site I'm trying to screen scrape:
https://www.mcdonalds.com.sg/locate-us/

Attributes I'm trying to get:
Address, Contact, Operating hours.

If you do a "right click", "view source" inside a chrome browser you will see that such values aren't available itself in the HTML.

---

Edit

Sry paul, i did what you told me to, found the `admin-ajax.php` and saw the body but, I'm really stuck now.

How do I retrieve the values from the json object and store it into a variable field of my own? It would be good, if you could share how to do just one attribute for the public and to those who just started scrapy as well.

Here's my code so far

**Items.py**

```
class McDonaldsItem(Item):
name = Field()
address = Field()
postal = Field()
hours = Field()
```

**McDonalds.py**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
import re

from fastfood.items import McDonaldsItem

class McDonaldSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "mcdonalds"
allowed_domains = ["mcdonalds.com.sg"]
start_urls = ["https://www.mcdonalds.com.sg/locate-us/"]

def parse_json(self, response):

    js = json.loads(response.body)
    pprint.pprint(js)
```

Sry for long edit, so in short, how do i store the json value into my attribute? for eg

***item['address'] = * how to retrieve ****

P.S, not sure if this helps but, i run these scripts on the cmd line using

scrapy crawl mcdonalds -o McDonalds.json -t json ( to save all my data into a json file )

I cannot stress enough on how thankful i feel. I know it's kind of unreasonable to ask this of u, will totally be okay even if you dont have time for this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*(I posted this to `scrapy-users` mailing list but by Paul's suggestion I'm posting it here as it complements the answer with the `shell` command interaction.)*

Generally, websites that use a third party service to render some data visualization (map, table, etc) have to send the data somehow, and in most cases this data is accessible from the browser.

For this case, an inspection (i.e. exploring the requests made by the browser) shows that the data is loaded from a POST request to https://www.mcdonalds.com.sg/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

So, basically you have there all the data you want in a nice json format ready for consuming.

Scrapy provides the `shell` command which is very convenient to thinker with the website before writing the spider:

```
$ scrapy shell https://www.mcdonalds.com.sg/locate-us/
2013-09-27 00:44:14-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.5 started (bot: scrapybot)
...

In [1]: from scrapy.http import FormRequest

In [2]: url = 'https://www.mcdonalds.com.sg/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'

In [3]: payload = {'action': 'ws_search_store_location', 'store_name':'0', 'store_area':'0', 'store_type':'0'}

In [4]: req = FormRequest(url, formdata=payload)

In [5]: fetch(req)
2013-09-27 00:45:13-0400 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.mcdonalds.com.sg/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php> (referer: None)
...

In [6]: import json

In [7]: data = json.loads(response.body)

In [8]: len(data['stores']['listing'])
Out[8]: 127

In [9]: data['stores']['listing'][0]
Out[9]: 
{u'address': u'678A Woodlands Avenue 6<br/>#01-05<br/>Singapore 731678',
 u'city': u'Singapore',
 u'id': 78,
 u'lat': u'1.440409',
 u'lon': u'103.801489',
 u'name': u"McDonald's Admiralty",
 u'op_hours': u'24 hours<br>\r\nDessert Kiosk: 0900-0100',
 u'phone': u'68940513',
 u'region': u'north',
 u'type': [u'24hrs', u'dessert_kiosk'],
 u'zip': u'731678'}
```

In short: in your spider you have to return the `FormRequest(...)` above, then in the callback load the json object from `response.body` and finally for each store's data in the list `data['stores']['listing']` create an item with the wanted values.

Something like this:

```
class McDonaldSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "mcdonalds"
    allowed_domains = ["mcdonalds.com.sg"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.mcdonalds.com.sg/locate-us/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # This receives the response from the start url. But we don't do anything with it.
        url = 'https://www.mcdonalds.com.sg/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
        payload = {'action': 'ws_search_store_location', 'store_name':'0', 'store_area':'0', 'store_type':'0'}
        return FormRequest(url, formdata=payload, callback=self.parse_stores)

    def parse_stores(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        for store in data['stores']['listing']:
            yield McDonaldsItem(name=store['name'], address=store['address'])
```

Comment: Thx for the help Rho it's informative and it worked ! *For those facing the same problem as me, do check this post out *

Answer (score 7):

When you open https://www.mcdonalds.com.sg/locate-us/ in your browser of choice, open up the "inspect" tool (hopefully it has one, e.g. Chrome or Firefox), and look for the "Network" tab.

You can further filter for "XHR" (XMLHttpRequest) events, and you'll see a `POST` request to `https://www.mcdonalds.com.sg/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` with this body

```
action=ws_search_store_location&store_name=0&store_area=0&store_type=0
```

The response to that POST request is a JSON object with all the information you want

```
import json
import pprint
...
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
...
    def parse_json(self, response):

        js = json.loads(response.body)
        pprint.pprint(js)
```

This would output something like:

```
{u'flagicon': u'https://www.mcdonalds.com.sg/wp-content/themes/mcd/images/storeflag.png',
 u'stores': {u'listing': [{u'address': u'678A Woodlands Avenue 6<br/>#01-05<br/>Singapore 731678',
                           u'city': u'Singapore',
                           u'id': 78,
                           u'lat': u'1.440409',
                           u'lon': u'103.801489',
                           u'name': u"McDonald's Admiralty",
                           u'op_hours': u'24 hours<br>\r\nDessert Kiosk: 0900-0100',
                           u'phone': u'68940513',
                           u'region': u'north',
                           u'type': [u'24hrs', u'dessert_kiosk'],
                           u'zip': u'731678'},
                          {u'address': u'383 Bukit Timah Road<br/>#01-09B<br/>Alocassia Apartments<br/>Singapore 259727',
                           u'city': u'Singapore',
                           u'id': 97,
                           u'lat': u'1.319752',
                           u'lon': u'103.827398',
                           u'name': u"McDonald's Alocassia",
                           u'op_hours': u'Daily: 0630-0100',
                           u'phone': u'68874961',
                           u'region': u'central',
                           u'type': [u'24hrs_weekend',
                                     u'drive_thru',
                                     u'mccafe'],
                           u'zip': u'259727'},

                        ...
                          {u'address': u'60 Yishuan Avenue 4 <br/>#01-11<br/><br/>Singapore 769027',
                           u'city': u'Singapore',
                           u'id': 1036,
                           u'lat': u'1.423924',
                           u'lon': u'103.840628',
                           u'name': u"McDonald's Yishun Safra",
                           u'op_hours': u'24 hours',
                           u'phone': u'67585632',
                           u'region': u'north',
                           u'type': [u'24hrs',
                                     u'drive_thru',
                                     u'live_screening',
                                     u'mccafe',
                                     u'bday_party'],
                           u'zip': u'769027'}],
             u'region': u'all'}}
```

I'll leave you to extract the fields you want.

In the FormRequest() you send with Scrapy you probably need to add a "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" header (your browser sends that if you look at the request headers in the inspect tool)