# Scrape data from an embedded google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, web-scraping

I read several related questions about scraping data from a google map, it seems that it is not possible. But we can find alternative solutions, for example, in this post : [Scrapy, scrapping data inside a Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021541/scrapy-scrapping-data-inside-a-javascript) the alternative solution is to find how data are loaded to the map.

**EDIT**: I didn't mean to ask people to code for me. I would like to know how to explore the code in order to get information.

For example the site of McDonald's SG, how do we find that there was a request for data?

Could you please tell if there are some key words that we can look for every time we want to scrap a page ? Thank you

Comment: I found this in the code, maybe it could help ? http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB6e5TrlTdRmb8pnpSwrg5pcKzT8rXUyVg&sensor=false

Comment: This is not a website to ask others to code for you. What about using your developer tools? Maybe you would find out that there is a call to a .json file... http://familyquick.fr/store-locator.json

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thank you very much. It is exactly the kind of information that I needed. Sorry that my question means to you that I want other people to code for me. I will reedit my question.

Comment: @MrUpsidown How did you know that there was a json file? When I downloaded the html file, I couldn't find any json file mentionned in the code. Thank you

Comment: Using Chrome -> Developer tools -> Network tab -> XHR (XMLHttpRequest) and you will see it loads that json file. It's basically loaded via AJAX.

Comment: Thank you very much @MrUpsidown. Could I ask you a question for another web site ? For this url : http://www.sephora.fr/Parfum/Parfum-Femme/C309/2, you can not directly get the page 2 (you have to refresh the page in your navigator to get the page 2). I use R (XML package) to read the page, and I always get the page 1. It seems that it is load via ajax too. Could you please help to find how I can get the data ? (I try your method with XHR for this site, it didn't work. Thank you

Comment: Seems they are injecting the stores in the JS code in another way... Try to open [this page](http://www.sephora.fr/storeLocator/fragments/storeLocatorMap.jsp) then "view source" and you can find a list of what seems to be all their stores. You should be able to extract the info somehow...

Comment: @Mark Setchell don't much understand your edit on the question... And you ask how I knew there was a json file. I didn't know there was a json file. I just opened my console and my eyes and found about it...

Comment: @MrUpsidown for sephora, I try this time to get their products (sorry I wasn't clear.) And for the question of finding the json file, my question wasn't clear: I tried to understand what tool you use, and your comment **perfectly** answered the question (with Chrome developer tools and network tab). I used the tool to inspect the html code and I didn't know how to use network tab. But now, thanks to you, I know.

Comment: Maybe you should think about not *stealing* their data... and ask them if they actually can provide you with a product list (could be json, XML, csv, etc.). Many shops do have that feature implemented as they often share their product lists with resellers or other websites. Could be worth asking... Otherwise you'd need to come up with a scraping tool of your own. There is not *always* an easy way...

Comment: Thank you very much @MrUpsidown for your comment. It is only for a personal project, so I think that the shop will not bother with me. Yes, I try to come up with a scraping script for divers web sites. I describe more my question with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37184509/web-scraping-oracle-atg-commerce Thank you for your comment, so that I know better now how to ask a good question. :)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @MrUpsidown, I know that I can use :

Chrome -> Developer tools -> Network tab -> XHR (XMLHttpRequest)

to see that it loads the json file. It's basically loaded via AJAX

Comment: tried your solution but am not able to get the geometry